# How do I take the user in my iOS app to the Messages Settings?

Tags: ios, url, settings

How would I take the user from my app to the Messages Settings?  I know the code to use, but I don't know the specific string literal to create the correct URL with to the UIApplication.shared.open(URL:options:) method with.  I think the literal needs to start with "prefs:root=".  It needs to be something like the following.  I just need to know what literal to use instead of "Messages".

```
    let urlString = "prefs:root=Messages"  

    let url = URL(string: urlString)!  

    let options: [String: Any] = [:]  
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: options) {  

        bool in  

        print(bool)  

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I have to use the string literal "App-Prefs:root=MESSAGES".

Answer (score 0):

```
let url = URL(string: "prefs:root=MESSAGES")!
UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
```

Will open Settings->Messages

Comment: I had tried that.  It didn't work until I changed the string literal to "App-Prefs:root=MESSAGES".  I don't know why.  I had found documentation saying the same thing you were saying.